# Oracle 12c - RMAN report unrecoverable

Tags: oracle, report, rman

I am having trouble checking my Oracle backups with RMAN.
The "report need backup" command does not display anything, which means that there is no problem ; but the command "report unrecoverable" asks me to do another backup :

```
RMAN> report need backup;

RMAN retention policy will be applied to the command
RMAN retention policy is set to recovery window of 7 days
Report of files that must be backed up to satisfy 7 days recovery window
File Days  Name
---- ----- -----------------------------------------------------
```

and

```
RMAN> report unrecoverable;

Report of files that need backup due to unrecoverable operations
File Type of Backup Required Name
---- ----------------------- -----------------------------------
45   full or incremental     /u01/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/data_ts3_01.dbf
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle doc "report unrecoverable;" will list: "Lists all data files for which an unrecoverable operation has been performed against an object in the data file since the last backup of the data file."
In other word, the instance doesn't have enough redo log to recover datafile. There are some missing redo and most of them take place when a non-logging operation has been specified (to speed up operation) using nologging clause.

The solution is to enable force-logging at database level.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for the delay. Indeed, I solved the problem by putting the database in force logging mode, as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Report Unrecoverable identifies datafiles in which nologging transactions have occured since the datafile was last backed up. Nologging operations are those that explicitly bypass gereration of redo. This redo would normally end up in archived redo log files which are included in your database backups. During database recovery, transactions are reapplied from these archived redo logs to the datafiles in order to reintegrate them into your database. So, in short, files reported by this command are ones in which nologging transactions will be lost if they must be restored from backup. These unrecoverable transactions do not prevent you from recovering your database from backup. It means they will be lost unless you backup these datafiles once again.